# Why does this mesh deform while weightpainting?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

When trying to weightpaint my mesh some mesh gets deformed.

[image]

I searched for an answer and found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32570/weight-painting-deforms-an-object?newreg=060e881204804d1b9eeb44fdd8b8879f) question, but the solution does not work. The problem only affect some bones - all bones which have a IK. If I subtract the weight paint the deformation goes back to normal.

The .blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JJXy7faTWvZDA2Q3o5ZldnNFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I subtract the weight paint the deformation goes back to normal.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend?

Comment: The post now links to the .blend file

Comment: Hi, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ in future for file-hosting. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting

Comment: Okay, will use that in the future. I'm new to this forum and didn't know that was a thing. Thx for the advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

The bones with a IK property applied to them where rotated slightly. This made so that the mesh rotated around to match the rotation of the bone.

How to fix

Check the rotaions of the bones in the vicinity of the deformation, in this case resetting the rotation on all the bones (suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32570/weight-painting-deforms-an-object?lq=1)) didn't help. I had to manually rotate the bones so that they didn't longer deform the mesh when the weight paint was applied.

---

[image: IK bone rotation]

Notice that the Z-rotaion is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

if you switch your armature to rest pose in the armature tab, properties editor, you can be sure that all bones are in their default orientation and location, even with constraints on them. thats easier and faster than manually trying to find them and resetting values.